# Component isn't updating after state change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I have read through 100's of these threads on here, and I can't seem to understand why my component isn't updating.  I am pretty sure it has something to do with the Immutability, but I can't figure it out.

The call is being made, and is returning from the server. The state is changing (based on the redux-Dev-Tools that I have installed).I have made sure to not mutate the state in any instance, but the symptoms seem to point that direction.

Code Sandbox of whole app https://codesandbox.io/s/rl7n2pmpj4

Here is the component.

```
class RetailLocationSelector extends Component {

componentWillMount() {
    this.getData();
}
getData = () => {
    this.props.getRetailLocations()

}

render() {
    const {data, loading} = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            {loading
                ? <LinearProgress/>
                : null}
            <DefaultSelector
                options={data}
                placeholder="Retail Location"/>
        </div>
    );
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        loading: state.retaillocations.loading, 
        data: state.retaillocations.data,
        osv: state.osv};
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return bindActionCreators({
       getRetailLocations,
       selectRetailLocation,
       nextStep
   }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RetailLocationSelector);
```

And here is my reducer :

```
    import {REQUEST_RETAIL_LOCATIONS, SUCCESS_RETAIL_LOCATIONS, 
ERR_RETAIL_LOCATIONS, SELECT_RETAIL_LOCATION} from 
'../actions/RetailLocationsAction'

    const initialState = {
        data: [],
        loading: false,
        success: true,
        selectedRetailLocation: undefined
    }

    function retailLocation(state = initialState, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case REQUEST_RETAIL_LOCATIONS:
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    loading: true
                }, {success: true})
            case SUCCESS_RETAIL_LOCATIONS:
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    loading: false
                }, {
                    success: true
                }, {
                    data: Object.assign([], action.payload.data)
                })
            case ERR_RETAIL_LOCATIONS:
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    loading: false
                }, {
                    success: false
                }, {errorMsg: action.payload.message})
            case SELECT_RETAIL_LOCATION:
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    selectedRetailLocation: state
                        .data
                        .find((rec) => {
                            return rec.id === action.payload.id
                        })
                })
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }

    export default retailLocation
```

And finally, my Action file:

```
import axios from 'axios';
//import {api} from './APIURL'

export const REQUEST_RETAIL_LOCATIONS = 'REQUEST_RETAIL_LOCATIONS'
export const SUCCESS_RETAIL_LOCATIONS = 'SUCCESS_RETAIL_LOCATIONS'
export const ERR_RETAIL_LOCATIONS = 'ERR_RETAIL_LOCATIONS'
export const SELECT_RETAIL_LOCATION = 'SELECT_RETAIL_LOCATION'
const URL = 'localhost/api/v1/retail/locations?BusStatus=O&LocType=C'

export const getRetailLocations = () => (dispatch) => {

    dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_RETAIL_LOCATIONS' });
    return axios.get(URL)
    .then(data => dispatch({ type: 'SUCCESS_RETAIL_LOCATIONS', payload: data }))
    .catch(error => dispatch({type : 'ERR_RETAIL_LOCATIONS', payload: error}));


}
```

Combined Reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import retailLocations from './RetailLocationsReducer'
import vendors from './VendorsReducer'
import receiptInformation from './ReceiptInfoReducer'
import osv from './OSVReducer'
import receiptDetail from './ReceiptDetailReducer'

const allReducers = combineReducers({
retaillocations: retailLocations,
vendors: vendors,
receiptInformation: receiptInformation,
receiptDetail: receiptDetail,
osv: osv

});

export default allReducers;
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are getting `data` in this component? What do you see when you put a `console.log( data )` in the `render` method?

Comment: are you getting any error messages in console ?

Comment: I just added a console log and am not receiving anything in data.  I am not getting any errors in the console.  In the Redux Dev Tools,  data is being set and contains information.  If i force the state to change (by pressing a different button on the parent component page), data gets populated

Comment: Can you put a `console.log( action.payload.data)` to your `retailLocation` function? Also, can we see your reducers config?

Comment: @ChrisCasola have you tried using `getDerivedStateFromProps`?

Comment: When i put a     console.log( action.payload.data) in the retailLocation function, it outputs all of the data. correctly.  I put it in the SUCCESS_RETAIL_LOCATIONS case.  
I have a combined reducer where I hook all of my reducers together (added to original post)

Comment: @Colin I have not, I have never heard of it.  I will take a look right now

Comment: Then, your reducer gets the data. Can you add a `state` property to your `mapStateToProps` function then `console.log( state )` in the render method?

Comment: @devserkan I did that,  and when the state prints, it doesn't show the data  in the tree.  I still had the log from the reducer, and that prints out the data after the state is printed

Comment: So, your component does not get new props. This is weird. If `state` is updated then it should get new props.

Comment: I've tried your code with a fake request and it works. Can you check your action types constants in case of there is a typo?

Comment: @devserkan I have checked for typos in the action and the reducer.  I didn't find anything .  I put a debugger in each case on the reducer, and the code seems to be going into them correctly.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/m47m1x9mjy Pretty much the same cod as yours. Just filenames are different. Can you put your code like that to codesandbox.io?

Comment: @devserkan https://codesandbox.io/s/rl7n2pmpj4   This is the whole project dumped into code sandbox,  I am getting the same result here as I do when i run it.

Comment: Ok, I need to go out right now but I will try to look at it tonight. Also, it is good to put your app there, not only me also other people can check it.

Comment: @ChrisCasola there doesn't seem to be anything in the `state.retaillocations.data` array, are you sure it's coming back from the API correctly?

Comment: @ChrisCasola not sure why there's no data there, but here's an example of how to make it update the render: https://codesandbox.io/s/ol5nvkxvz.

Comment: @Colin I added the `componentWillReceiveProps` and it doesn't seem to be getting in there after the axios call returns

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't solve your issue totally but provides some hints about what is not working. The broken part is your `store` definition. I don't have much experience with `redux-devtools-extension` or `redux-batched-subscribe` but if you define your store like that your `thunk` function works:

```
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

One of the configuration for the mentioned packages above brokes your `thunk` middleware.

Comment: `redux-batched-subscribe` was the problem. I took that package out and that solved it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm not quite sure you should choose my answer as accepted. It is up to you at this point I think :)